# I'm getting error when using the chatterbot in python 3.x

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot

So this was my code:

```
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot import chatbot
bot = chatbot('Dona')
conv = open('sample.txt', 'r').readlines()
bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)
bot.train(conv)
while True:
    query = input("You: ")
    reply = bot.get_response(query)
    print("Bot: ", response)
```

And there's this error I get, I think it's unable to import the program

```
enter code here

from pytz import UTC
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'
```

This is the last line of error.

Comment: try installing module "pip install pytz".

Answer (score 4):

Install [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) to your python environment:

```
pip install pytz
```